# How to #include a different file each time based on user input?

Tags: c, include

I have a program which, depending on the user input, `#includes` one header `headerA.h` or another `headerB.h` I expect the header to be there till the end of the program.

`headerA` and `headerB`  define structures with the same names but with different fields, and I'm not able to merge both files in one, and neither able to change anything else from the libraries that `headerA` and `headerB` are using.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is possible to conditionally include files, it does not seem to be possible to have this change during runtime. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930360/c-conditional-include-file-runtime) about it. The if statements only work before runtime.

Comment: Okay, this was probably the answer I didnt want to hear. There's any way to define two different structures with the same name and different fields depending on a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor macros:

```
#if defined(USE_HEADERA)
# include "headerA.h"
#elif defined(USE_HEADERB)
# include "headerB.h"
#else
# error must define USE_HEADERA or USE_HEADERB
#endif
```

If you have GCC then you tell the preprocessor which to select using the GCC `-D` option:

```
$ gcc -DUSE_HEADERA myfile.c -o myprogram
```

---

However, if you want to do it *runtime* during execution that's impossible. `#include` is a preprocessor directive, and the preprocessor only runs as part of the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible as your `#include`s are resolved before compilation i.e during preprocessing. So it is not possible to change them during runtime.

But you can try conditional compilation by defining a macro during compiletime.

```
#ifdef HEADERA
  #include <headerA>
#ifdef  HEADERB
  #include <headerA>
```

While compilinging gcc

`$ gcc prog.c -DHEADERA` to include headerA or vice versa